# Initializing a c++ array with another one

Tags: c++

```
struct AType {
  const byte data[4];
  AType(const byte d[]):data{d[0],d[1],d[2],d[3]} {}
  ...
};

const byte SERIALNR[4] = {0,0,9,0xFF};

AType SNr {SERIALNR};
```

This works, but I consider it a bit ugly. Is there a syntax with a shorter initializer list?
And: How to do it, if that magic 4 were a template parameter?

The initialization of SERIALNR is just to make the sample complete, my goal is to implement something nice, allowing

`AType SNr {SERIALNR};`  or similar

And yes, that thing should be able to be constructed as **const**, if possible

Comment: use `std::array` instead

Comment: how about `AType SNr {0,0,9,0xFF};` ?

Comment: May i introduce you to current year C++? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array

Comment: Yes, @Taekahn: modern c++ is more than c + classes. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do this using a combination `std::array` and `std::initializer_list`. Also you can have the size of the array to be a template parameter:

```cpp
using byte = unsigned char;

template <int S>
struct AType {
  std::array<byte, S> data;
  AType(const std::array<byte, S> &d) : data(d) {}
  AType(const std::initializer_list<byte> &d)  {
      std::copy(d.begin(), d.end(), data.begin());
  }
};

int main(){
  AType<4> SNr1 {0,0,9,0xFF}; // Uses the constructor with initializer_list as parameter
  AType<4> SNr2 {{0,0,9,0xFF}}; // Uses the constructor with std::array as parameter
  return 0;
}
```

Live example: https://godbolt.org/z/vjKbbr67G

Comment: Thanks. BTW: The constructors do not need to be defined explicitly for this sample AType